# Javascript throwing an error in is null or not an object

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make a slide show gallery and used the example at URL - http://mediaeventservices.com/2007/11/15/ajax-image-gallery-powered-by-slideflow-like-cover-flow/

When I view it in FF it works fine however IE and chrome give me an error:

```
“is null or not an object”. 
Message: Object required
Line: 66
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Romona/P%20drive%20backup/componets/slideShow/slideShow4/slideShowGallery/gallery.html
```

IE developer tools indicate that the below line is causing the problem:

```
var imgSrc = ‘photos/large/’+ photos.item(photoNumber – 1).getElementsByTagName(“src”)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and examine the various expressions that are in that line... (select an expession, then hover or add to watch). Somewhere in this chain `photos.item(photoNumber – 1).getElementsByTagName(“src”)[0].childNodes[0]` there is a `null` value.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, i hope your real code doesn't have smart quotes `“src”` and has dumb quotes instead `"src"`.

Second, `getElementsByTagName("src")` isn't going to work.  That will find `<src>` tags.  But you probably want `<img>` tags instead, so search for `"img"` instead.

I think `getElementsByTagName("src")` returns an empty array because nothing is found, getting the first item with `[0]` returns `null`, and calling `childNodes` on `null` raises this error.

---

At the very least, try breaking that line up and see what steps return something you don't expect.